# impose datatype with read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql

My table1 have 20 columns, 3 from these are in timestamptz.
When trying to run my query, as shown below,

```
    d_rows = pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=connection)
```

For my timestamptz columns, i saw that the types stored in my dataframe (object, datetime64, datetime64). And for these datetime64, the data was stored in UTC.

My idea is to impose datatype object, if the type in source is timestamptz to read the right value and not utc.

Thank you,

x

Comment: Can you show sample data? Otherwise, if I understand correctly, just delete the time frame. So for the given columns it is enough: `df['timestampColumn1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestampColumn1).dt.tz_localize(None)`

Comment: I don't want to remove the zone. I want to store the data like it is in the source.

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: date1: 1970-12-31 23:00:00+00:00 and date2: 2021-09-06 13:29:53.326000+00:00 . Let's notice that the first date1 was stored as datetime64 and date2 was stored as object. @Cesc

Comment: date 1 is in the source 1971-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 and date2: 2021-09-06 13:29:53.326000+00:00

Comment: @Cesc is it clear for you now?